# Short form file names when viewed in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, filenames

I realise that this is possibly more of a Windows question than a Linux one, but maybe someone knows the answer or can point me to a suitable better forum (I shall post the same on Stack Overflow), and it is to do with the interface between the two.
I recently moved my external backup NAS drive from a Windows10 machine over to my Linux box (Raspberry Pi running Buster).  My backup script runs on the Linux box (it was before too, it is just that the drive location has changed).

I did have a bit of trouble getting the drive mounted reliably and in the process reformatted the drive from scratch (having backed up what I wanted and copied it back again).  Still NTFS formatted. In the end my I/O mount problems turned out to be due to a flaky USB connection through a USB hub, probably did not need to have reformatted but it may be relevant to know that I did so. The disk is now mounted on the Windows box from a Samba share.

Everything is working fine except for the fact that when I view the list of created files on the linux box everything looks as expected - like so:

```
norman@SarabandP1:~ $ ll /mnt/MyPassport/DBbackups/
total 256816
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8931219 Nov 22 04:30 DBbackup_2020-11-22T04:30+00:00.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8931219 Nov 24 04:31 DBbackup_2020-11-24T04:30:54.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8952403 Nov 25 04:30 DBbackup_2020-11-25T04:30:49.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8931219 Nov 23 04:30 DBbackup_23-11-2020T04:30:49.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8580047 Oct 25 04:30 DBdump_2020-10-25T04"30+00"00.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8580047 Oct 26 04:30 DBdump_2020-10-26T04"30+00"00.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8580047 Oct 27 04:30 DBdump_2020-10-27T04"30+00"00.sql
```

Whereas if I look at the list in Windows Explorer I see short form file names BUT ONLY FOR FILES CREATED SINCE I MOVED THE DRIVE!

```
C:\Users\norma>dir M:\DBbackups /o-d
 Volume in drive M is MyPassport
 Volume Serial Number is 6FFF-C645

 Directory of M:\DBbackups

25/11/2020  04:30         8,952,403 DG9YLA~V.SQL
25/11/2020  04:30    <DIR>          .
24/11/2020  04:31         8,931,219 DIGOUP~2.SQL
23/11/2020  04:30         8,931,219 DV8NG7~5.SQL
22/11/2020  04:30         8,931,219 D9R9AO~S.SQL
21/11/2020  11:01    <DIR>          ..
19/11/2020  04:30         8,930,931 DBdump_2020-11-19T0430+0000.sql
18/11/2020  04:30         8,930,931 DBdump_2020-11-18T0430+0000.sql
17/11/2020  04:30         8,930,912 DBdump_2020-11-17T0430+0000.sql
16/11/2020  04:30         8,930,912 DBdump_2020-11-16T0430+0000.sql
15/11/2020  04:30         8,930,912 DBdump_2020-11-15T0430+0000.sql
14/11/2020  04:30         8,930,912 DBdump_2020-11-14T0430+0000.sql
```

You can see a change in file name formats - but that is only because I experimented a bit to see if the format made a difference, I noticed the issue immediately before I tinkered with the file names.

If all filenames were shortened I could think it was to do with the fact that I was interacting through a Samba share - but the fact that only files since the move are appearing that way baffles me.

Any clues as to what is happening would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Windows does not allow `:` or `"` as part of a filename

Comment: Thanks Panki, looks like that is the issue - I shall adjust my filename formats